# Rails Sass media query variables cause Heroku push to fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sass

I am using Sass directive/variable to define screen-size on my media query. However, my app is failing to compile while pushing to Heroku.

Error from Heroku build log.

> rake aborted! Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...ia (max-width: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "@screen-xs-max) {"
>          /tmp/build_79af979930797464252714c06ee51080/bizdesc-com-bizdesc-276487d/app/assets/stylesheets/page.scss:2
>          /tmp/build_79af979930797464252714c06ee51080/bizdesc-com-bizdesc-276487d/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss:5

Line five is this line on my SCSS file: @media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) { ... }

My page.scss file

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */   
@media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) { ... }

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and upto desktops, 992px) */   
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) and (max-width: @screen-sm-max) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and upto large desktops, 1200px) */   
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) and (max-width: @screen-md-max) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */   
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close due to typographical error (hint: that's not how you reference variables).

Comment: @cimmamon I think it would be more useful to answer this saying how one *should* reference variables.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Answering this question will be of no use to future users, that's why we close questions where the problem is caused by a typographical error.

Comment: @cimmanon Writing a `@` instead of a `$` 6 times, as the poster has done here, indicates an error of **understanding** rather than a typographical error: no-one makes the same typo six times.  Answering their question corrects this error and it's possible others in the future may make the same error.  I agree that often questions may seem so simple that they have no value but i think it's debatable whether that is the case here.

Comment: So, the issue here was mixing LESS with SASS so, in SASS I needed to change the @ to $ having defined the variables first somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Reference your variables with `$` not `@`

```
@media (max-width: $screen-xs-max)
```

http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-2

Comment: @bir_ham did it solve your issue?

Comment: Yes. I was mixing LESS with SASS so, in SASS I needed to change the @ to $ having defined the variables first somewhere.